# Alert using VBA to scan a column and send message to Telegram

Tags: excel, vba, telegram

I have setup remote temp readings that update in excel every second.
When the internal temp reading in Col C equals the external temp in col E, the corresponding row in col G will highlight as a match and display the property and room where the match exists.
I would like to know if it is possible for VBA code to be applied to do the following:
Scan/loop Column G and if the row is not blank to take the output and send via telegram as an alert system.
As the temperature moves a lot I would only like to be alerted once every hour but would prefer to leave the possibility of having this as a variable setting eg. every 5,10,15.20 mins linked to the excel document should I wish to change it. Any help would be most appreciated.
Any help would be most appreciated.

[image]

I have used the code so far for sending the code on telegram, my only issue is being able to create a loop on column G to find any non blank cells within a variable timeframe and linking it to send the message via telegram.

Telegram code:

```
Sub Main_Routine()
  ''' The first parameter is the recipient's number (NOT the gateway number), including the country code.
  ''' The second paramter is the content of the message.
  TelegramMessage_Send "12025550108", "Alert message here"
End Sub


Sub TelegramMessage_Send(ByRef strNumber As String, ByRef strMessage As String)
  Dim CLIENT_ID As String, CLIENT_SECRET As String, API_URL As String
  Dim strJson As Variant
  Dim sHTML As String
  Dim oHttp As Object

  ''' TODO: Replace the following with your gateway instance ID, your Premium client ID and secret:
  INSTANCE_ID = "YOUR_INSTANCE_ID_HERE"
  CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE"
  CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
  API_URL = "http://api.whatsmate.net/v1/telegram/single/message/" & INSTANCE_ID

  strJson = "{""number"": """ & strNumber & """, ""message"": """ & strMessage & """}"

  Set oHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
  oHttp.Open "POST", API_URL, False
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "X-WM-CLIENT-ID", CLIENT_ID
  oHttp.setRequestHeader "X-WM-CLIENT-SECRET", CLIENT_SECRET
  oHttp.Send strJson

  sHTML = oHttp.ResponseText
  MsgBox sHTML
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at `Application.OnTime`